# How can I set a context for Dialogflow from my Flutter app (flutter_dialogflow_v2 plugin)

Tags: flutter, dialogflow-es

I have a Flutter app that sends user queries to Dialogflow.
My goal is to not just send the query from the user but also set a context from my app so Dialogflow matches an intent according to the given context.

When I test my code below, it returns an instance of aiResponse:

```
{responseId: null, queryResult: null, webhookStatus: null}
```

But every element in there is null, so something did not work correctly.
I expected to see a result with all the necessary information, most important the queryResult.fulfillmentText which is the answer from Dialogflow.

I use this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dialogflow_v2

This is my code:

```
    List<Context> contexts = [
      Context(name: 'start', lifespanCount: 10),
    ];

    DetectIntentResponse aiResponse = await dialogflow.detectIntent(
      DetectIntentRequest(
        queryInput: QueryInput(
            text: TextInput(
          text: finalQuery,
          languageCode: Language.english,
        )),
        queryParams: QueryParameters(
          contexts: contexts,
        ),
      ),
    );

    print(aiResponse.queryResult.fulfillmentText); //throws error because queryResult is null
```

I am pretty sure it does not work because of the contexts I set in there.
When I remove them from my code it works fine.
Maybe I am setting the contexts list in the wrong way?

I can also set contexts from my fulfillment Node function in Dialogflow.
Then I would have to send a query to Dialogflow which triggers an intent which then sets the context for the actual query from the user.
That's not the way I would like to do it, because the plugin already offers this functionality.

I hope there is somebody who can help me with my problem, because I am not sure if it is the plugin or just me.

Comment: Should I add information to make my problem more understandable?

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed it.
I am using a different plugin now, but it might also work with the plugin I used before.

I am using dialog_flowtter now:

```
  dialog_flowtter: ^0.2.0
```

This is my code:

```
void response(query) async {
    DialogAuthCredentials credentials =
        await DialogAuthCredentials.fromFile("assets/service.json");

    final DialogFlowtter dialogFlowtter = DialogFlowtter(
      credentials: credentials,
      sessionId: "12345678",
    );

    final QueryInput queryInput = QueryInput(
      text: TextInput(
        text: query,
        languageCode: "en",
      ),
    );

    final params = QueryParameters(
      contexts: [
        Context(
            name:
      "projects/{project_id=*}/locations/{location_id=*}/agent/environments/{environment_id=*}/users/{user_id=*}/sessions/{session_id=*}/contexts/start",
            lifespanCount: 10),
      ],
    );

    DetectIntentResponse response = await dialogFlowtter.detectIntent(
      queryInput: queryInput,
      queryParams: params,
    );
    print(response.text);
}
```

The context name is right at the end of the context name string and I called it "start" with a lifespan of 10.